# Changing opacity of a texture on the fly in opengl?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new to opengl and have no idea how to deal with opacity. I have two layers that are overlapped i am drawing both the layers on to the screen. I want to fade out the one in the foreground to transtition to the background image. Is there any way to do this?? Here's my draw method.

```
public void draw(GL10 gl10) {
    gl10.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl10.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl10.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_TRUE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl10.glClearColor(0F, 0F, 0F, 0);
    gl10.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.mTextureId);
    this.layer1.draw(gl10); // i want to transition from this layer
            this.layer2.draw(gl10); // to this layer by changing opacity
            }
```

I dont know even i framed my question correctly. Hope you get it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the method you're using for this transition. I have a similar situation with an animation view. About your opacity problem, can't you use

```
View v;
int i = 0; /*Values from 0 to 1, float cast might be needed for intermediate values*/
v.setAlpha(i);
this.layer2.setAlpha(i);
```

Or something like that, isn't this applicable in your case?

Comment: Btw, "cange" the title ;-)

Comment: All the layers contains sprites rendered from a single textures. There is no support for alpha in my method. All i do is just replicate the texture.